# Lua, seial number replacement

Tags: lua

Part of my code is like this:

```
Load_name:addLoad({'incrementalnodalload',        7,           1,    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
```

the last part (I mean 1,2,...,10) can be extended as much as required (for example 1,2,...,1000).

Thus I want to replace this part with something like this:

```
Load_name:addLoad({'incrementalnodalload',        7,           1,    inc_number})

inc_number = 1:1000
```

However, it does not work!

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Use a for loop to append integers to a table, then pass it to `addLoad`. Lua doesn't support what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried to do it but the problem is that the numbers should be separated with comma "," (for example  1, 2, 3,   ,100) and I don't know does "insert.table" is capable of doing that!?

Answer (score 2):

Here is `inc_number` function that accepts two parameters and does what you need in this context:

```
function inc_number(f,t)
  if f > t then return else return f,inc_number(f+1,t) end
end
Load_name:addLoad({'incrementalnodalload', 7, 1, inc_number(1,100)})
```

Note that it only works when the result of `inc_number` call is the [last parameter in the list of parameters](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.10). Example:

```
print(table.concat({inc_number(1,10)}, ","))
-- prints: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: +1 but you should explain "the last parameter" is because of Lua's support for tail calls, in case OP or other readers want to find out more about the technique

Comment: @Schollii, thank you; added a link to the appropriate section in the documentation. The tail call doesn't apply because of `return f,func()`, as it needs to be `return func()`.